# Notification not received in foreground in release ipa

Tags: ios, flutter

I have integrated firebase for push notifications in flutter. If the app is in foreground I have displayed a dialog with notification details. I am receiving notifications properly in android. Also when I run the ios application from XCode notifications are working fine. However in release ipa notifications are not received in foreground but working well in app background state. I have enabled push notifications and background fetch as well. Any solution for this? Has anybody faced such issue?

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications not showing notifications strip in foreground mode.
Please check in the delegate method that you are receiving or not.

Comment: I am working on flutter. still I need to check in delegate?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this link
May be it will help you
https://medium.com/@viveky259259/flutter-firebase-notifications-7954a3ad8111